# I need help with Grep to start at a section

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

I have some text files that I want to grep a section of code from. The goal I am trying to achieve is to start the view at a certain line & then be able to read anything below it. For example. In the text below, how do I view the text file at the start point of yellow.  I want to view the content of "yellow" as well as everything underneath it, regardless of what that content is.

```
green
blue
cyan
magenta
purple
brown
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**AWK**
Use `AWK` - that's the simplest as it can get:

```
awk '/yellow/,0' textfile.txt
```

Sample run

```
$ awk '/yellow/,0' textfile.txt                                
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough
```

**Grep**

You could also use `grep` with `--after-context` option, to print certain amount of lines after the match

```
grep 'yellow' --after-context=999999  textfile.txt
```

For automatic setting of context, you could use `$(wc -l textfile.txt)` . The basic idea is that if you have a very first line as a match and you want to print everything after that match, you will need to know the number of lines in file minus 1. Luckly, `--after-context` won't throw errors about the number of lines, so you could give it number completely out of range, but in case you don't know it, total number of lines will do

```
$ grep 'yellow' --after-context=$(wc -l < textfile.txt) textfile.txt
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough
```

If you want to shorten the command `--after-context` is the same option as `-A` and `$(wc -l textfile.txt)`, will expand to number of lines followed by file name. So that way you type `textfile.txt` only once

```
grep "yellow" -A $(wc -l textfile.txt)
```

**Python**

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./printAfter.py textfile.txt                                 
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat ./printAfter.py                                          
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

printable=False
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
     for line in f:
        if "yellow" in line:
           printable=True
        if printable:
           print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Or alternatively without `printable` flag

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
     for line in f:
        if "yellow" in line:
          for lines in f: # will print remaining lines
             print lines.rstrip('\n')
          exit()
```

Comment: You can simplify the `grep` command to `grep "yellow" -A $(wc -l textfile.txt)`.

Comment: @ByteCommander yup, can be done as well. Just used full option for clarity

Comment: @ByteCommander What a lovely hack. Unfortunately it only works because there are no spaces in the file name.

Comment: @kasperd Oh yes, you're right. In that case, you would have to fall back to Serg's original command `grep "yellow" -A $(wc -l < "my colors.txt") "my colors.txt"`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by:

```
awk '/yellow/{f=1}f' file
```

where "file" is the file name containing your text.

Comment: Great minds think alike >:)

Answer (score 5):

Not `grep`, but using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^yellow$/,$p' file
```

- `-n`: inhibits printing
- `/^yellow$/,$`: address range that goes from the first occurence of a line matching exactly `yellow` to the last line inclusive
- `p`: prints the lines in the address range

```
% sed -n '/^yellow$/,$p' file
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough
```

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party :)

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\n\Kyellow\n.*' file.txt
```

- `-P` enables us to use Perl compatible Regex
- `-z` makes the input file separated by ASCII NUL, rather that newline
- `-o` takes only the desired portion
- `(?s)` is the DOTALL modifier, enables us to match newline using token `.` (any character)
- In `\n\K`, `\n` matches a newline, `\K` discards the match
- `yellow\n.*` matches `yellow` followed by a newline and everything after this is selected too and shown in the output.

**Example:**

```
% grep -Pzo '(?s)\n\Kyellow\n.*' file.txt
yellow
red
orange
more orange
more blue
this is enough
```

---

Using little `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print ''.join(lines[lines.index('yellow\n'):])
```

- `lines` is the list containing all the lines of the file (with trailing newlines too)
- `lines.index('yellow\n')` gives us the lowest index of `lines` where `yellow\n` is found
- `lines[lines.index('yellow\n'):]` will use list slicing to get the portion starting from `yellow\n` till end
- `join` will join the elements of the list to output as a string

Comment: Nice, but you should mention that the Python code only finds entire lines that equal to "yellow", it does not detect e.g. lines like "more yellow".

Comment: @ByteCommander From OP's example i think its clear that they want to match just `yellow` in the line..also if that is not the case then we need to change the `python` one's algo..

Comment: Yeah, sure. That wasn't criticism anyway, just a hint to improve the answer. Somebody else reading this might assume that the code works like `grep` and does not match only full lines. I upvoted btw.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question refers to *viewing* the file, there's always the good ol'

```
less +/yellow file
```

Comment: Didn't know `less` can do that. Very nice !